# what is the difference between a system and an object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Guys I want to know the difference between a system and an object ?
A system is collection of two or more objects but how ca we define an object suppose if we talk about a tennis ball its an object but at atomic level we can say it is a system because it is made of millions of atoms and each atom can be  considered as an object . 
But can we consider a half part of the ball as an object and other half as another  object if they are still connected as a single ball  not separated .
Are there some guidelines when we say some thing is object or this is an arbitrary choice and we can divide any object into more objects according to our need .

Comment: I think you are looking for a degree of precision in terminology that simply isn't there. We'd probably use the term *object* if the internal degrees of freedom of a *system* could be ignored for the purposes of our calculation or experiment. For example if your aim is to predict where a thrown ball will land it's probably irrelevant how many atoms it's made of. However the term is inherently vague.

Comment: I am not talking about linguistics  here  I am only asking  about a scientific (physics) concept.

Comment: I wasn't talking about linguistics. I don't think scientists have an exact definition of the words *system* and *object*. Systems have subsystems, and they have subsubsystems, and at some point a sub$^n$system gets simple enough that we don't care about its internal structure. Then we call it an object. But there is no hard and fast rule.

Comment: now got it simple as that.

Comment: @JohnRennie Those comments look suspiciously like an answer to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object will be whatever you want to treat as an object.

If you were concerned about where the tennis ball would go, treating it as two half tennis balls would be a waste of effort.  The system that the two half objects form will be essentially the same as considering the ball as a single object.

Ideally your object will be easy enough to deal with as an object.  If it is too complicated, you could consider it a system of many objects, and use what those objects are doing to determine the behaviour of them system (or the bigger object).

It's all relative to what you are trying to determine and the accuracy required.  For Newtonian physics for example, you don't want to think of the system of atoms, because then Newtonian physics doesn't apply.

Comment: so it depends on the problem and on my choice and convenience and there are no special guidelines to determine whether the thing is object or not .

Comment: Exactly.  Objects are arbitrary and really only a labelling term for explaining the math and whatever.  Deciding between objects and systems is really just how you arrange the problem.

Comment: Well that was really helpful and easy to understand the way you described it .

Answer (score -1):

The concept of an "object" is a product of human intelligence. It's our ability to discern parts of reality from one another given our macroscopic view. Reality at a more basic level is excitations/propagations of continuous fields, not concrete cut and dry boundaries as our macroscopic view would imply. At a lower level, it's doesn't make much sense to talk in terms of "objects". It's like looking at the earth from up in the sky... you see various boundary lines that seem clear from your point of view. The closer you go, the harder it is to define a precise point where this section ends, and this other section begins.